# Create pose-array in Halcon

Tags: halcon

Ive seen a pose array a few times generated by a Halcon procedures like find_surface_model.
When I try to create one myself I cant get it to work.

I tried `tuple_concat()` and a few array notation things but the result is the same, one lengthy array.

How can you make a pose-array? Would like to know for HDevelop as well as Halcon.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about C#, but in HDevelop the difference is only the semantic type of the tuple. That can be changed using a procedure: First, concatenate all the poses; then make a procedure that has one input and one output tuple, and simply copies the input into the output. In the procedure's settings, set the sem_type of the output tuple to "pose". You can then use that procedure to convert your tuple into a pose array.

Comment: Look a bit like a workaround but I'm gonna try it, Thank you for your suggestion!